# Using the chain rule for proof

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

how would I use the chain rule and partial derivatives to do this question:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try differentiating the first expression with respect to $t$. A particular value of $t$ substituted into this expression will give you what you want..